# Overloading the Double Parentheses function and using it inside the same class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Im overloading the Double Parentheses function and using it inside the same class for a matrix in c++? Im confident I overloaded it properly but I do not know how to call it from inside itself.

Comment: Your question is lacking some example code...

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that your Double Parentheses function is `operator()`, then you can call it from inside other member functions in two different ways:

```
    unsigned operator()(unsigned i) const
    {
        if(i == 0) return 1;
        return operator()(i-1);
    }
```

or

```
    unsigned operator()(unsigned i) const
    {
        if(i == 0) return 1;
        return (*this)(i-1);
    }
```